# Parallax effect isn't working on small devices

Tags: html, css, parallax

I created a college project named as Online-Insurance-Management *Responsive to screen width*, I tried to add the parallax effect to it... N it worked perfectly fine!! I was happy about it. But when I hosted it on xampp n tried to open the site on my mobile, it was a mess...

The code I used for parallax effect is:

```
        .box1 {
            background-image: url(./Images/Background-Image.jpg);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            top: 50px;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

Whenever I try to run the site on my old mobile this happens:

[image: Screenshot]

*****Don't worry about the navbar getting out of position, my other teammate is working on it*****

Also, I did EVERYTHING THAT I COULD DO!!! For ease, I am sure that the PROBLEM is somewhere in Internal CSS I applied on the HOME page.

***I can't use javascript here because it's out of syllabus***

Please help me out here... Pretty Please...

In case you need to view the full project source: https://github.com/belikeParamjot/Online-Insurance-Managment/